# Ubuntu server 18.04 LTS getting CIFS VFS: Free previous auth_key.response =

Tags: server, 18.04, samba, shared-folders, cifs

I recently set up Ubuntu server 18.04 LTS on an old laptop to use as a Plex Media server, and wanted to connect it to my existing media share on my QNAP NAS. I set this up using CIFS, and it seems to work, but every now an then i get the following message appear on the screen.

```
CIFS VFS: Free previous auth_key.response = 0000000076b9d676
```

The number at the end always changes.
How do I get rid of this message??

Btw here is how I setup access to the share

## Install cifs-utils

```
sudo apt install cifs-utils
```

## Create mount directory

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/nas_media
```

## Create credentials file

```
cat > ~/.smbcredentials
username=myusername
password=mypassword
ctrl+c

sudo chown root ~/.smbcredentials
sudo chmod 600 ~/.smbcredentials
```

## Get UID for plex user account

```
id -u plex
```

I'll be using 113 as the UID for this example

## Backup fstab file

```
sudo cp /etc/fstab /etc/fstab-old
```

## Add share to fstab

```
sudo vi /etc/fstab
```

press <kbd>i</kbd> to enter insert mode
go to end of file and enter a new line
add the following

Note ip, sharename and username have been changed for privacy.
Also vers=3.0 was set because that is the version of samba I have set on my nas.

```
//192.168.1.50/MyShare /mnt/nas_media cifs vers=3.0,iocharset=utf8,credentials=/home/myusername/.smbcredentials,uid=113 0 0
```

type :wq to save and exit vi

## Load the new mount point

```
mount -a
```

btw I've also rebooted the server and the message always comes back.
Plex is able to read and write to the share, so I'm not too sure why this message is coming up.

Is there anything I missed?

Comment: `vers=` is used for the [SMB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Message_Block) version and not [Samba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samba_(software)).   Chances are you might be running Samba v4.3.  You might want to check the protocol version on your NAS by looking up the specs.

Comment: This also looks to just be a message and possibly nothing to worry about.  https://www.systutorials.com/linux-kernels/59092/cifs-release-auth_key-response-for-reconnect-linux-4-13-5/  Even my 16.04 system reports it with checking `sudo journalctl -p 3 -xb`

Comment: ok thanks, i'll check into the smb vs samba version

Answer (score 0):

It looks like someone [posted a request about this on Redit's Fedora page](https://www.reddit.com/r/Fedora/comments/7o53sq/anyone_else_getting_cifs_vfs_free_previous_auth/).  The consensus there seems to be that there is a [kernel patch coming down the pipe](https://lore.kernel.org/patchwork/patch/836460/) which will fix this.